# JWT authenticated succesfully, but the postman return 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, http-status-code-404

SO, this is my first time using jwt as an authentication for my API, I've seen many example from other source and finally i wrote into my code like below. (please don't mind about unused variable on there).

My goal is to authenticate any request from **/engagement/**** endpoint using generated jwt from login phase with my sso, then decode that jwt and verify it when hit the engagement API, until this point, and when i saw my log, any authentication running smoothly when I hit my engagement API.

But, finally, instead of returning my json data (Yes it have engagement data in my database), postman always give me error 404 and I don't know why.
what's wrong with this?

**AuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${fintax.app.client_secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Something went wrong while parsing /login request body";
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;
    
    AuthenticationFilter(final RequestMatcher requiresAuth) {
        super(requiresAuth);
    }
    
  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

      
      String token  = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");      
      String secret = clientSecret;
      
      String bearer = token.replace("Bearer", "").trim();

      Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret));
      JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
         .withSubject("xxxx-xxxx@xxxx.id") //i'm hardcoded this for testing
          .build();

      DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(bearer);
      
      UserModel user = new UserModel();
      user.setUserId(jwt.getSubject());
      
      List<GrantedAuthority> authorities =  AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("");
      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);

  }
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

        // As this authentication is in HTTP header, after success we need to continue the request normally
        // and return the response as if the resource was not secured at all
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    
    
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


 private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
  new AntPathRequestMatcher("/engagement/**")
 );


 @Override
 public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
  webSecurity.ignoring()
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login")
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/logout");
 }

 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.sessionManagement()
       .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
       .and()
       .exceptionHandling()
       .and()
       .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
       .authorizeRequests()
       .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
       .authenticated()
       .and()
       .cors().and().csrf().disable();
     
 }

 @Bean
 AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
  final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
  filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
  //filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
  return filter;
 }

 @Bean
 AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
     return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
 }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {

        var tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {

                var securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");

                var collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {

        var connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

        return connector;
    }
     
}
```

**Postman Log**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-28T06:10:52.881+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/"
}
```

**UPDATE**

So i've checking the postman console and it have suspicious log like this pic, my post method somehow always dropped then postman redirecting to get method and root url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the filter after.

```java
    @Override
    public void addFilters(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i've tried this but still facing same issue.